# Definition of composition used in Axler's proof 3.101, Algebraic Properties of Dual Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-maps

My question is regarding Axler's proof of this Algebraic Property of dual maps:
$(ST)' = T'S'$ for $T\in\mathcal{L}(U,V), S\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ where $T',S'$ represents the dual map.

In the last step of the proof, he says that $T'(S'(\varphi)) = (T'S')(\varphi)$ by the definition of composition.

I understand composition to be $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$, where $f,g$ are functions. Which I thought was different from $(fg)(x)$. Am I misunderstanding that? Is multiplying functions together really the same as the composition? Or is there some property of dual maps that make this possible?

Source: Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler, 3rd ed.

Comment: Composition could be written without the $\circ$

Comment: See Definition 3.8 on page 55 of Linear Algebra Done Right (third edition) for the convention that if S and T are linear maps such that S compose T makes sense, then this composition is denoted by ST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're saying is correct: In the case of linear maps multiplication is precisely composition. If you want some intution on why that's the case think about the fact that a linear map can be represented by a matrix.